# python key press to interrupt time.sleep()

Tags: python-2.7

I have a program that spends a lot of time asleep in an endless loop, it checks in with another system API every 6 hours, and if there are changes does some stuff, if not goes back to sleep.

Without listing all the code, its pretty simple; I have

```
while True:
    do some stuff
    time.sleep(21600)
```

The only way to break this is with CTRL+C, but that seems ugly, is there a way to make another keypess interrupt the time.sleep() and use a graceful sys.exit()?

Comment: For me, in Python 3.7.3, control-c doesn't interrupt the sleep, even if I setup a signal handler to handle a SIGINT signal.  I think that's a new behavior.   Seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's exactly what you are searching for, but I found a solution using [pynput](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput).

The following implementation is basically their [reference implementation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) with your loop added.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep

exit_flag = False

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        global exit_flag
        exit_flag = True
        print("SET EXIT TO {}".format(exit_flag))
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release) as listener:

    print("listen...")

    while not exit_flag:
        print("do something...")
        sleep(2)

    listener.join()
```

The workaround with the global exit condition is not the cleanest solution, but it does it's job.

**EDIT:**

I realized that you want to actually exit during sleep, which is also not possible with the implementation proposed. But would it be an option to catch the keyboard interrupt and perform the sys.exit() there? Would be quite a simple solution.

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    try:
        print("do something")
        time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("to be able to exit script gracefully")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill have to read up on your first solution, but If I understand correctly it wont catch a keyboard press while the script is sleeping.

With the second one it looks like the user has to catch the script while its not sleeping as well.

Comment: Exactly, the first one will finish the sleep() and exits afterwards. The second one will catch the CTRL+Z at any time (work and sleep). Do you search a way just to interrupt the sleep?

Answer (score 0):

i am not writing any code, but here is my idea... instead of a big sleep time like `sleep(21600)` make a loop that runs 21600*1000 times and sleep for a millisecond, and in that loop keep listening for keyboard interrupt or keypress. the code is going to be ugly so i suggest use abstraction.

P.S. why 21600*1000 and not "21600 and sleep for a sec", a sec is not to precise. The probability that you'll press keyboard interrupt while `sleep(1)` is active is more than if you use milli or micro second.

Comment: will the work be heavy if the 1 time big sleep to become 1000 times small sleep?