# Python infinite loop until I press a certain key

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to run a script infinite amounts of time until I press a certain keypress.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import keyboard

while True:
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    fname = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\pythontestscreenshot\\capture1.png"
    im.save(fname)
    time.sleep(5)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F9"):
        break
```

I want the script to end even when its "sleeping" whenever I press F9 but it doesn't work. It only works when I press F9 when the time.sleep ends.

Comment: `sleep()` blocks the thread which is executing the code therefore no other instructions are executed during the 5 seconds

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607895/python-key-press-to-interrupt-time-sleep